# How to fetch all columns from DB to a model using PDO, apart from selected columns?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

In Laravel you can declare some properties in the model which will not be fetched, how to do this in pure PHP / SQL? My controller method looks like this:

```
public function getUserByUsername($username)
{

    $db = new Db();

    $query = $db->conn->prepare("SELECT id, userName, firstName, lastName, phoneNumber, userType, compliant, emailVerified, phoneVerified FROM apiAccount WHERE userName = :userName");
    $query->bindParam(':userName', $username);

    if($query->execute())
    {
        $db = null;
        $query->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, 'AccountModel');
        $result = $query->fetchAll();
        if (isset($result[0])) {
            $db = null;
            return $result[0];

        } else {
            $db = null;
            throw new APIException('Query could not be executed, user not found', 600, null, 'User does not exist');
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $db = null;
        throw new APIException('Query could not be executed', 600, null, 'Dodgy SQL');
    }
}
```

And my model:

```
class AccountModel extends BaseModel
{
    public $id;
    public $userName;
    public $firstName;
    public $lastName;
    public $phoneNumber;
    public $userType;
    public $compliant;
    public $emailVerified;
    public $phoneVerified;
}
```

Basically, I don't want to constantly add stuff to my query every time I add or amend the column in the database. I just really want to skip password being fetched automatically when I fetch the user info into my model. Please point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to add a constructor to your model that takes an array and only sets its properties that exist.

```
function __construct($properties = []) {
    foreach ($properties as $key => $value) {
        if (property_exists($this, $key)) $this->$key = $value;
    }
}
```

Then fetch an associative array and construct the instance of the model from that.

```
if($query->execute())
{
    $db = null;
    $result = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    if ($result) {
        return new AccountModel($result);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this!! I added the constructor to my BaseModel which all the models extend. Now I'm just questioning whether this is something that other programmers do? I see a benefit of it mainly in development as I might be adding columns and I don't want to modify all the queries every time, i rather leave them as `SELECT * FROM` and only modify model properties instead, to choose what is fetched. Also, I don't want to always fetch passwords or tokens, unless I use a speciffic method just for that. Does this approach have some caveats I might not be aware of? Is this a common practice?

Comment: Hi @Varin, you're welcome! I'm really not sure if something like this is a common practice to be honest. It's something I just thought of, not something I've really used. I would probably not do it this way if I was designing the system. I would rather have a repository method that takes the model and constructs a query dynamically using its defined properties to determine which columns are selected.

Comment: Thanks! I just had a quick chat with a friend who does .net, he pretty much said the same thing. I could really use some ORM instead but I'm trying to build an API from scratch without frameworks. The above approach doesn't really help with performance as SQL fetches everything anyway, so really, the only thing it is doing is putting only the declared properties into my models, and skipping those not declared. I will look into what you just said as it is definitely the better approach. (I won't get offended if you copy paste that method though :P )